# C++ drawing a Tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, visualization

I googled for a Tree Visualization Framework or something like that in C++ .
And i wondered that i didn't find anything like that.
Are There any (good) Framework to draw a Tree (or other Data Structures) ?
It should be in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For simple tree, you can use standard tree control of your GUI environment (Win32 API, Gtk, Qt, whatever). If you need it to be cross-plaform, you can use wxWidgets or Qt.

If you are looking for something more generic, take a look at [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).